# Pins in OpenROV that control the motors?

Tags: mobile-robot, beagle-bone

I'm working on my own ROV project, but I find OpenROV have a [ready to use image](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software/releases/tag/v2.5.0) for my BB so want to use that instead of making my own program, and I already deployed the image, but I can't find which three pins find that send PWM signal for ESC's? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### OpenROV Cape

If I understand things correctly,
the OpenROV motors are connected to ESCs that are connected to Arduino Digital pins 9, 10, and 11.
According to the ["ATmega168/328-Arduino Pin Mapping"](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168), that corresponds to physical pins 15, 16, and 17 respectively on the 28-pin ATmega328 DIP.

[image]
A nice diagram on the OpenROV wiki showing a photo of the OpenROV Cape and where to connect the Port, Vertical, and Starboard ESCs to the cape
(diagram from https://forum.openrov.com/t/wiki-buildout/1585 ).

[image]
The Arduino IDE is used to program the ATmega328 in a 28-pin DIP package on the other side of the OpenROV Cape, shown here.
(photo from 
["Bluebird Marine Systems: OpenROV underwater robots for educational exploration"](http://www.bluebird-electric.net/artificial_intelligence_autonomous_robotics/open_rov_source_underwater_robots_for_exploration_education.htm))

Why are there 2 not-quite-the-same Arduino firmware folders,
https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software/tree/v2.5.0/arduino/OpenROV
and https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software-arduino/tree/master/OpenROV ?
I'm guessing that the "openrov-software-arduino" version is the latest version.

The [OpenROV Cape.h file](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software-arduino/blob/master/OpenROV/Cape.h) defines those pins:

```
#define PORT_PIN 9
#define VERTICAL_PIN 10
#define STARBOARD_PIN 11
```

Those definitions are used in the [OpenROV Thrusters2X1.cpp file](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software-arduino/blob/master/OpenROV/Thrusters2X1.cpp)

```
Motor port_motor(PORT_PIN);
Motor vertical_motor(VERTICAL_PIN);
Motor starboard_motor(STARBOARD_PIN);
```

The above lines pass the pin numbers to the Motor constructor declared in [Motor.h](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software-arduino/blob/master/OpenROV/Motor.h).
Later the [OpenROV Motor.cpp file](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software-arduino/blob/master/OpenROV/Motor.cpp) stores those pin numbers and passes them to functions in the [openrov_servo.cpp file](https://github.com/OpenROV/openrov-software-arduino/blob/master/OpenROV/openrov_servo.cpp) to control the ESCs.

### BeagleBone PWM

Some of the pins on the BeagleBone are internally connected to a hardware PWM driver.
Some people have several ESCs or other things controlled by a standard [RC control signal](http://www.opencircuits.com/Servo_control), each one driven by one such pin on a BeagleBone.

(FIXME: this would be a good place for a link to the part of the OpenROV code that runs on the BeagleBone and sends a message to the Arduino with the desired PWM; can that bit of code can be tweaked to directly drive that desired PWM out the BeagleBone pins?)

- Simon Monk. Adafruit. ["Controlling a Servo with a BeagleBone Black"](https://learn.adafruit.com/controlling-a-servo-with-a-beaglebone-black/overview)
- Ben Martin. ["How to Control a Servo Motor from a BeagleBone Black on Linux"](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776799-servo-control-from-the-beaglebone-black).
- ["BoneScript: analogWrite"](http://beagleboard.org/support/BoneScript/analogWrite/)
- Meng Cao. ["How to use all the GPIO on Beaglebone Black in Python"](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/fall13/group05/meng.pdf)
- Akkana. ["GPIO tutorial for the BeagleBone Black"](http://shallowsky.com/blog/hardware/beaglebone-black-gpio.html)
  implies that the BeagleBone Black hardware PWM can drive up to 8 pins (?).
- Justin Cooper. Adafruit. ["Setting up IO Python Library on BeagleBone Black: Using GPIO, PWM and more with Python"](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/pwm)
- Babak Parvizi. ["BeagleBone Black ... Controlling a Servo Using HTML5, JavaScript, and Node.js."](http://digital-drive.com/?p=146)
- ["Working with PWM on a BeagleBone Black"](https://briancode.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/working-with-pwm-on-a-beaglebone-black/).
- Saad Ahmad. ["beaglebone-black-cpp-PWM"](https://github.com/SaadAhmad/beaglebone-black-cpp-PWM).
- eLinux. [BeagleBoardPWM](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardPWM)
- Hipstercircuits. ["Enable PWM on BeagleBone with Device Tree overlays"](http://hipstercircuits.com/enable-pwm-on-beaglebone-with-device-tree-overlays/).
- ["Using the BeagleBone‎: Using PWM outputs"](http://beaglebone.cameon.net/home/using-pwm-outputs) describes how to drive 6 servos from a white BeagleBone.

Comment: So the ESC isn't connected directly with BBB? I don't have an Arduino and I don't see the need of it, can I change the control of OpenROV image to drive using BBB pin instead? Where is the image you're talking about?

Comment: The OpenROV cape is Arduino-compatible. After you have that, I agree that you don't need *another* Arduino board to build a OpenROV.

Comment: Well I'm looking to make a ROV project with a BBB only without additional component that OpenROV using, I just want to borrow the OS..